# how to generate bridgedataoutput api access token

Tags: c#, token

i register on https://bridgedataoutput.com/ for using bridge data api.  as per documents
https://bridgedataoutput.com/docs/platform/API/zg-data#Zestimates

require access token.  how I get access token  ?

after login , I get detail of Client id, Client Secret and Server Token. i try server token but give me authorization error.

I try to do get request on this below API link

https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/zestimates_v2/zestimates?access_token=P7cbhWXt2PLOGOHbctzuOJ1qF2mJYSSF7cI1IrUabGdt3u2IGMiFzu5XLCNk&address=%22123%20Main%20Street%22

Response

`{"success":false,"status":403,"bundle":{"name":"AuthenticationError","message":"Invalid access_token format"}}`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and Bridge support said to use the Server Token as the access token. It needs to go in the URL, not as a header when I tried it. Here's an example.

`https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/OData/[DATASET_ID]/[RESOURCE]?access_token=[SERVER_TOKEN]`

Comment: I use sever token but for use Zestimate api give error

https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/zestimates_v2/zestimates?access_token=P7cbhWXt2PLOGOHbctzuOJ1qF2mJYSSF7cI1IrUabGdt3u2IGMiFzu5XLCNk&address=%22123%20Main%20Street%22

Comment: Yep. You need another token probably. One authorized to do that, but they won't ever tell you that part of the story.

Comment: Can you please help how i get this another token ?

Comment: That I don't know. We tried, but Zillow rejected our application for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Zillow Public Records, Zestimates and Econimic Data does need additional approval. Please confirm in https://bridgedataoutput.com/data/feeds.